# In my Bluehost control panel, in the file manager, my files are being mysteriously replaced

Tags: cpanel

For example, I will upload my index.html, but then like an hour later it will be replaced with a file with a file size of 0 bytes.

Comment: can you provide more examples? or is it just this one file?

Comment: It's happening with different files....php, txt, jpg...any files I upload.  Bluehost doesn't know what it could be.  This is crazy.

Comment: Any other details? Does the filename stay the same? Is there _any_ pattern?